# How do I fix this issue with these harsh dark-shaded polygons?

Tags: mesh

Whenever I move the camera/light around I get these harsh shading on these polygons. Any ideas?

[image: Dark-Shaded areas]

Comment: try select all faces in the Edit mode and hit Ctrl N to Make Normals Consistent (or spacebar + write it)

Comment: Hi, Jan. Thanks for the reply. That doesn't seem to resolve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Just to clarify on what I did:

I selected all of the faces and tried recalculating normals but it just made everything darker (as if it were using the normals from the dark-shaded faces). I also tried selecting just the problematic faces and then recalculating but it issue is still there.

And I displayed the normals and they're all front-facing.

Comment: Why mark this as a duplicate? As mentioned above, I've already tried that fix in that thread and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: When the entire mesh goes darker you can then use the *flip normals* command described in the other question I linked to, to invert all the normalized normals.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Unfortunately, that didn't seem to fix it.

However, I did kind of hacked my way around the issue. I just replaced those problematic faces with the faces of the rings that are located above/below it since those normals seem to be working just fine.

How can I marked this as solved or just close the thread?

Comment: Please upload your blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so we can investigate your issue closely